# First Step Easy, Second Step the Challenge

Tags: cipher

Below is a simple substitution cipher. There are a number of online tools that could solve this in seconds. The easy first step, therefore, is to decode the text to it's original.

> Bhrp pbwyq phecc bhi swwo uem bieah hrp pwm;
>   Emo Ayrpfrm Ayrpfrem phecc mi’iy sw tq,
>   Nywu bhrp oeq bw bhi imorms wn bhi jwyco,
>   Tvb ji rm rb phecc ti yiuiutiyio-
>   Ji nij, ji heffq nij, ji temo wn tywbhiyp;
>   Nwy hi bw-oeq bheb phiop hrp tcwwo jrbh ui
>   Phecc ti uq tywbhiy; ti hi mi’iy pw krci,
>   Bhrp oeq phecc simbci hrp awmorbrwm;
>   Emo simbciuim rm Imscemo mwj-e-tio
>   Phecc bhrml bhiupickip eaavyp’o bhiq jiyi mwb hiyi,
>   Emo hwco bhiry uemhwwop ahief jhrcip emq pfielp
>   Bheb nwvshb jrbh vp vfwm Permb Ayrpfrm’p oeq.

The second step is to figure out the rule by which the cipher's key was made. That may seem broad but there is a very definite  order by which each letter was assigned which might seem very obvious once the key is laid out.

My goal is to provide a relatively simple challenge as well as to test how effective this method may be applied as a piece to a larger puzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is:

> This story shall the good man teach his son;
> And Crispin Crispian shall ne’er go by,
> From this day to the ending of the world,
> But we in it shall be remembered-
> We few, we happy few, we band of brothers;
> For he to-day that sheds his blood with me
> Shall be my brother; be he ne’er so vile,
> This day shall gentle his condition;
> And gentlemen in England now-a-bed
> Shall think themselves accurs’d they were not here,
> And hold their manhoods cheap whiles any speaks
> That fought with us upon Saint Crispin’s day.

The key is

> ETAOINSHRDLCUMWFGYPBVKJXQZ0123456789

which is just

> the English alphabet ordered by frequency. A is encoded to the first most common letter, B to the second, and so on.

Comment: Can you give a name of the program, or the link to the site you used to crack the cipher? Might be usefull in the future.

Comment: @TheDarkTruth: I used [QuipQiup](http://quipqiup.com) to figure out the gist of it, then the [Rumkin Cryptogram Assistant](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/cryptogram.php) to extract the precise text and the key.

Comment: @Deusovi I used Rumkin to encode it and QuipQiup to double-check it so you did exactly what I did except in reverse except that the numbers aren't really a necessary part of the key. That's very satisfying.

Comment: @Eng: Huh, cool!